# How to stop proguard from removing joda time resources on Android

Tags: android, proguard, jodatime

I use ProGuard and Joda Time in my Android application (of course, I use a version optimized for Android: https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android). I ran into the problem that with optimization and obfuscation turned on, I get an error when I try to use `PeriodFormat`:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key PeriodFormat.space
```

I compared the contents of the APK when building with and without proguard and saw that the org/joda/time/format directory in the non-optimized version contains 15 properties files, and only 9 in the optimized version. In these files I saw the PeriodFormat.space keys, so leaves no doubt that the exception caused by the loss of these files.

How to configure proguard so that the contents of this directory are transferred to the optimized APK without any optimizations?

I already use the following rules for Joda Time:

```
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-keep class org.joda.** { *; }
-keep interface org.joda.** { *; }
-keepdirectories org.joda.**
```

However, they are not enough, because the files still disappear.

Comment: `-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-keep class org.joda.time.** { *; }
-keep interface org.joda.time.** { *; }`

Comment: Hm... It helped. But why? I thought ** should include all nested packages (i.e. org.joda.** wider than org.joda.time.**).

Comment: Yes @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: Kindly post as answer if you solved it.

Comment: I just applied suggested by you options. Also I cleaned project and rebuilt it. I don't exactly know what helped.

Answer (score 4):

> java.util.MissingResourceException: can't find resource for bundle
>   java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key PeriodFormat.space

**Don't**

```
-keep class org.joda.** { *; }
-keep interface org.joda.** { *; }
```

**Do**

```
 -keep class org.joda.time.** { *; }
 -keep interface org.joda.time.** { *; }
```

Your [**`proguard`**](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/index.html#manual/introduction.html) will be

```
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-keep class org.joda.time.** { *; }
-keep interface org.joda.time.** { *; }
```

Read [**`-keep options`**](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage#keepoptions).