# Android : Proguard build is failing for joda time

Tags: android, proguard, jodatime, android-jodatime

I am getting the following error when I build the app with proguard. This failure is new. I updated some of the libraries used in the app to latest (including the target and compile sdk version to 30)but the joda library version is not changed. It is **implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.8.2'**
Any idea why this error is coming now and how it can be resolved.
I already have the rule `-keep class org.joda.** { *; }` in my progurad rules.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.xxx.xxx.xxx: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read ZoneInfoMap
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleMakeApplication(ActivityThread.java:7506)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7440)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:301)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read ZoneInfoMap
    at net.a.a.a.a.a(SourceFile:42)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.onCreate(SourceFile:116)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192)
```

### EDIT

Updating joda version to the latest 2.10.9.1 fixes the issue.
I am not adding this as answer as I wanted to know why this error appeared all of a sudden? Can any other version update can lead to this.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52949688/13373270

Comment: no, it did not work with that but it works if I add -keep class net.danlew.** { *; }

Comment: Also wondering what made this to come now as I have not changed the joda lib version